# cannot po swift object in super class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

First of all, I have set swift compiler optimization to None in XCode.

I have some swift code in my Objective-C based project, and I can compile, declare swift objects in my Objective-C code, seems they are playing well with each other.

however, when I was debugging a method in a class's super class implementation, when I tried to po self.delegate, it shows:

```
(lldb) po self.delegate
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
self.delegate
^
```

`po self` or other local variable has same issue.

However, if I use frame variable self.delegate, it can actually show values

```
(lldb) fr v self.delegate
(ChartViewDelegate?) self.delegate = (instance_type = 0x0000000102d08840 (void *)0x0000000102d08868: RadarChartViewController): {
  instance_type = 0x0000000102d08840 (void *)0x0000000102d08868: RadarChartViewController
}
```

How can I fix it? Anything should I set?

Comment: did you find out the reason why?

Comment: no, but I wasn't suffer from this right now

Comment: @Nico I remember I set the swift conpiler optimization level to None for debug mode. Seems can help.